# Issue using 'force_style' for subtitles in FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I've recently run into an issue in using FFMPEG's 'force_style' filter. Adding subtitles by themselves works just fine, but when force_style parameters are included, I get "Option 'force_style' not found."

Here's the input:
`ffmpeg -i (input.mp4) -vf "subtitles=(input.srt):force_style='FontSize=20,BorderStyle=3'" (output.mp4)`

Historically, this has worked on this machine and continues to work on others in the office (and seems to be independent of version).

```
(File) matched with its srt
Commencing ffmpeg closed captioning command...
ffmpeg version 2.3.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
built on Jan 11 2016 11:12:29 with Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.3.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --enable-vda --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid --enable-libfreetype --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-ffplay --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libopus --enable-libquvi --enable-libx265
   libavutil      52. 92.100 / 52. 92.100
   libavcodec     55. 69.100 / 55. 69.100
   libavformat    55. 48.100 / 55. 48.100
   libavdevice    55. 13.102 / 55. 13.102
   libavfilter     4. 11.100 /  4. 11.100
   libavresample   1.  3.  0 /  1.  3.  0
   libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
   libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
   libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from (File):
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
encoder         : Lavf55.48.100
Duration: 00:01:47.65, start: 0.042667, bitrate: 877 kb/s
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 730 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 139 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : SoundHandler
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x7f8d98600740] Option 'force_style' not found
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7f8d9840c300] Error initializing filter 'subtitles' with args '/Users/Username/Desktop/Combined/KMTV0402-Do_You_Have_A_Thyroid_Disorder.srt:force_style=Fontsize=20,Borderstyle=3'
Error opening filters!
```

As a side note, we're not running the most recent version of FFMPEG as an additional program conflicts with some recent updates.

Thanks in advance for any help/suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `force_style` option was added in `libavfilter 5.9.104`. Your build has version `4.11.100`. You'll have to upgrade.

If you upgrade to a [static build](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html), you shouldn't have any conflicts.